# Tomcat PooledConnections Using MYSQL

Tags: java, mysql, tomcat, jdbc, connection-pooling

I am creating a RESTful webservice using jersey 2.0 which connects to a mysql database using Tomcat connection pooling. I have run into an issue where when I set the maxActive connections to anything greater than 1, I receive the following error message after about 15 subsequent request calls.

**Data source rejected establishment of connection,  message from server: "Too many connections"**

My understanding of pooling is it will create the max number of connections configured and then start reusing those connections, providing them on an as needed basis. I originally suspected a leak in the code but after review I am not sure what the issue could be. When maxActive is set to 1 the issue does not occur.

Here is my code.

```
public DatabaseManager(Properties connProps){
    this.connProps = connProps;
    this.createConnection();
    this.createTableRepository();
}

public void createConnection()
{
    try {
        Context context = new InitialContext();
        Context envCtx = (Context)context.lookup("java:comp/env");
        this.dataSource = new DataSource();
        PoolProperties props = new PoolProperties();
        props.setUrl(this.connProps.getProperty("url"));
        props.setUsername(this.connProps.getProperty("username"));
        props.setPassword(this.connProps.getProperty("password"));
        props.setDriverClassName(this.connProps.getProperty("driverClassName"));
        props.setMaxActive(Integer.parseInt(this.connProps.getProperty("maxActive")));
        this.dataSource.setPoolProperties(props);
    } catch (NamingException e) {

    }
}

private void createTableRepository()
{
    this.tableRepository = new TableRepository();
    Connection connection = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    try {
        connection = getPooledConnection();
        DatabaseMetaData dbMeta = (DatabaseMetaData)connection.getMetaData();
        rs = dbMeta.getTables(null, null, "%s", null);
        while(rs.next()){
            String tableName = rs.getString(3);
            TableMeta table = new TableMeta(tableName);
            ResultSet columns = dbMeta.getColumns(null, null, tableName, null);
            while(columns.next()){
                table.addColumn(columns.getString(4));
            }
            this.tableRepository.addTable(tableName, table);
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally{
        if(rs != null){
            try{
                rs.close();
                rs = null;
                }
            catch(SQLException e){}}
        if(connection != null){
            try{
                connection.close();
                connection = null;
                }
            catch(SQLException e){}}
    }
}

private void executeStatement(IDBQuery dbQuery)
{
    Connection connection = null;
    PreparedStatement statement = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    int rows = 0;
    try {
        connection = this.dataSource.getConnection();
        statement = connection.prepareStatement(dbQuery.toString());
        if(dbQuery instanceof DBQuerySelect){
            rs = statement.executeQuery();
            if(rs != null){
                dbQuery.populateQueryResuls(rs);
            }
        }
        else {
            rows = statement.executeUpdate();
            if(rows > 0){
                dbQuery.populateQueryResults(rows);
            }
        }
        if(rs != null){
            rs.close();
        }
        if(statement != null){
            statement.close();
        }
        if(connection != null){
            connection.close();
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    finally {
        if(rs != null){try{rs.close(); rs = null;}catch(SQLException e){}}
        if(statement != null){try{statement.close(); statement = null;}catch(SQLException e){}}
        if(connection != null){try{connection.close(); connection = null;}catch(SQLException e){}}
    }
}

public Connection getPooledConnection(){
    Connection con = null;
    try {
        con = this.dataSource.getConnection();
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return con;
}
```

I am calling the connection in two methods, each one closing the ResultSet, Statement, and Connection in the finally block to guarantee they are closed. I am at a loss as to what could be causing the connections to max out.

I am using mysql-connector-java-5.1.38.jar for connections.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where do you call `createConnection()` from? Where is the code for `getPooledConnection()`? Where do you call `executeStatement()` from?

Comment: Thank you for the reply Gergely. I have added the methods getPooledConnection() and executeStatement();

Comment: Thank you for the comment Gergely. I have added the missing methods. I am calling createConnection from the constructor of the DatabaseManager class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't create your own Datasource object. Tomcat does it for you. Check the [sample code in its documentation](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/jndi-resources-howto.html#JDBC_Data_Sources) and rather follow it.

Further, if your creation of the Datasource object (in your method `createConnection()`) runs into any problems, you'll leave a half-configured datasource.

Lastly: Make sure you call your `createConnection` method only once.

If this all doesn't help: Show us your Tomcat-Datasource configuration (e.g. the xml)

Comment: I resorted to creating my own DataSource because the JNDI route of creating a context.xml file was not working for me. I am calling createConnection from the DatabaseManager class constructor.

Answer (score 0):

The answer by @Olaf Kock got me investigating my original context.xml file located under the META-INF folder. Originally, I was using Tomcat to create my JNDI DataSource by configuring the context.xml file. This stopped working some days ago and so I resorted to creating the DataSource myself.

After reading Olaf's comment, I went back to my context.xml file with fresh eyes and realized the name had been changed to content.xml! This lead to an error message **org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create JDBC driver of class '' for connect URL 'null'**  which several days ago I could not make sense of. Now that I am back to using the JNDI to create my DataSource, I am no longer receiving the max-connections error message. I am still not sure why creating my own DataSoure would cause the issue since I was closing out all connections per the tomcat documentation. The only conclusion I can come to is that by creating my own DataSource inside the construct of my DatabaseManager class, I was creating a separate DataSource each time which had its own connection.

Thank you for your responses.